# shiny app with nginx cookie based authentication (LDAP / Active Directory)

Tags: r, nginx, shiny

We have successfully managed to deploy and authenticate shiny apps with nginx cookie-based authentication and it is using LDAP / Active directory of our company.
However, I need to extract the cookie provided by nginx to the browser to customize the UI of the apps based on the **user**. In other words, I need to find out who has logged in to the app.
cookies are **httponly** and they cannot be accesses with js.

Answer (score 2):

You can push `cookie` information to the server with `Shiny.onInputChange`. Once you have it, parse it and extract the information you need, such as the user using `grep`. If you're not sure what the `cookie` contains, have a look at the `console.log(document.cookie);`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    # send cookie to the server
    tags$script('$(document).on("shiny:connected", function(e) {Shiny.onInputChange("cookie",document.cookie);});')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    observeEvent(input$cookie,{
        req(input$cookie)
        # parse cookie here
    }) 
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It prints out only the table, there is no information about the cookie in the output.

Comment: have a look at the update

Comment: How can I retrieve and see the information in this object? because I need to filter the data and reshape the UI based on this information?

Comment: Yes you would need to parse it, as I suggested use `grep`

Comment: the output of the latest update is a white screen.
there is no information about the cookie

Comment: Everything is self-explanatory, as an Snr Analyst you should have no problems parsing it

Comment: I just found out that these are **HttpOnly**  cookies and cannot be accessed through document.cookie. any ideas on how to get these cookies?